# How to get Java scanner to acknowledge blank input?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, bigdecimal

I am having trouble getting my program to respond to empty inputs. For example, say I wanted to prompt the user to enter a value for money with type `BigDecimal` as well as a currency type. Here is what the program in question looks like.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the amount of money " 
                             + "and specify currency (USD or CNY): ");

    // initialize variable moneyInput
    BigDecimal moneyInput;

    // check if moneyInput is numeric
    try {
         moneyInput = input.nextBigDecimal();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.err.println("InputMismatchException: non-numeric value");
        return;
    }

    // specify currency of moneyInput
    String currencyType = input.next();

    ...
}
```

So here, an input like `100.00 USD`, works fine.

```
Enter the amount of money and specify currency (USD or CNY): 100.00 USD
$100.00 USD ≈ ￥670.17 CNY
```

An input like `ASDF USD` appropriately results in the error message.

```
Enter the amount of money and specify currency (USD or CNY): ASDF USD
InputMismatchException: non-numeric value
```

But, how do I force the program to respond to blank inputs, either immediately pressing the return key or entering a bunch of spaces in the first line? For example:

```
Enter the amount of money and specify currency (USD or CNY): 





1000.00 USD
$1000.00 USD ≈ ￥6701.70 CNY
```

In the above example, the user can just press the return key indefinitely until something readable (valid or invalid) is entered. **I want to implement some way to check if the user pressed the return key without entering anything meaningful**.

Another outcome that I don't know how to account for is if the user enters ONLY the monetary value, then presses [return] a bunch of times before finally inputting the currency.

Example:

```
Enter the amount of money and specify currency (USD or CNY): 100.00



USD
$100.00 USD ≈ ￥670.17 CNY
```

How do I get the program to prompt the user with something like `Please specify the currency:` after a numeric value is input and the user presses [return]? Something like

```
Enter the amount of money and specify currency (USD or CNY): 100.00
Please specify the currency: USD
$100.00 USD ≈ ￥670.17 CNY
```

I was able to achieve the above functionality by changing the part after the try-catch block to:

```
input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Please specify the currency: ");
String currencyType = input.nextLine();
```

But using this method, the program loses the ability to allow the user to input both `moneyInput` and `currencyType` in one line, like in the first example. (And again, there is still the problem of being able to press [return] indefinitely for each of these prompts until something readable is finally input).

Thanks for reading and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Scanner` offers two basic - and sometimes conflicting - use cases:

1. Read input by *tokens*, disregarding any whitespace inbetween (this is what your initial code does)
2. Read input by *line*, without treating any contents of those lines specially

Generally speaking mixing the two is a poor idea (it works, but probably not how you intend). The token-reading methods like `next()` and `nextBigDecimal()` ignore newlines.

If you want to handle <kbd>Enter</kbd> you need to read a user's input line-by-line with `Scanner.nextLine()` and parse each line individually (i.e. `line.split("\\s+")`), rather than use `Scanner`'s token-reading methods.

Some people like to use nested `Scanner`s and read input line by line with one `Scanner` then pass the line into a new `Scanner` to tokenize just that line.

For example:

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    try {
      String line = in.nextLine();
      Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
      BigDecimal moneyInput = lineScan.nextBigDecimal();
      String currency = lineScan.next();
      // do something
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | IllegalStateException e) {
      System.err.print("Please enter the VALUE followed by the CURRENCY");
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you don't want to use a nested `Scanner` there are a number of other roughly-equivalent mechanisms. Here's the gist, but you'll likely want to add additional error-handling code (e.g. if `new BigDecimal()` throws an exception:

**Using `String.split()`:**

```
String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
if (parts.length == 2) {
  BigDecimal moneyInput = new BigDecimal(parts[0]);
  String currency = parts[1];
  // do something
} else {
  System.err.println("Please enter the VALUE followed by the CURRENCY");
}
```

**Using `Pattern`:**

```
/**
 * Matches one or more digits, optionally followed by a . and more digits,
 * followed by whitespace then one or more uppercase letters.
 */
private static final Pattern MONEY_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))\\s+([A-Z]+)");
```

Then:

```
Matcher m = MONEY_PATTERN.matcher(line);
if (m.matches()) {
  BigDecimal moneyInput = new BigDecimal(m.group(1));
  String currency = m.group(2);
// do something
} else {
  System.err.println("Please enter the VALUE followed by the CURRENCY");
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please show how to use the parse method with `line.split("\\s+")` to achieve the same result? I'm not familiar with that method so I'm having a hard time with the syntax. Thanks

Comment: Added more examples.

Comment: Ok, how could I separately check if `currency` is valid? I want it to act in the same way as with `moneyInput`, i.e. if something like `100.00 abc` or `100.00` is entered, the user is repeatedly prompted for `currency` only, and once they enter a valid currency like `USD`, the program resumes normally. I tried using another do-while loop inside to check currency, and this worked except for when a blank input was entered, which is basically the same problem I had at the beginning of this post (here is my code: http://pastebin.com/raw/CT0qjBPk and program screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/mjfaL).

Comment: I also tried using a second set of nested Scanners followed by another `try` block, all inside a `while` loop (pretty much mirroring your first solution). Everything worked fine, including being able to respond to a blank input when re-prompting for `currency`, but I ran into some new problems (see: http://pastebin.com/kEUQSEFF and http://imgur.com/a/W6WWB).  I am continually working on this so if I fix some of these errors, I'll be sure to update. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: If you're trying to work with money I'd strongly suggest the [Joda-Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) library - among other things it has a regularly updated [database of currencies](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/joda/money/MoneyData.csv) so that you don't have to do validations yourself. The behavior you're describing (prompt for both, but validate and re-prompt individually) is non-trivial, and would be best discussed in a separate followup question rather than in comments. If you link me to it I'd be happy to take a swing at it.

Comment: Good idea, and thanks for taking the time to help. Here's the updated follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38557212/5606164 It's already been answered since it's a simple question, but please give it a look if you can.