# Using Nested Scanners to Check for Blank Inputs, but [Return] key must be pressed twice

Tags: java, string, loops, input, do-while

This question serves as a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471220/how-to-get-java-scanner-to-acknowledge-blank-input/38471264).

I am trying to create a program that converts from one currency to another.

First, I'll post and explain the relevant code, then describe the desired outcome and some problems I came across.

```
do {
    try {
        invalidInput = false;

        String line = input.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        BigDecimal moneyInput = lineScan.nextBigDecimal();

        // second do-while loop that tries to emulate the outermost do-while loop
        // introduces a second set of nested scanners
        // re-prompts user for valid currency if they try a blank input
        do {
            try {
                String line2 = input.nextLine();
                Scanner lineScan2 = new Scanner(line2);
                String currency = lineScan2.next();
                if (currency.equals("USD")) {
                    // convert USD to CNY
                } else if (currency.equals("CNY")) {
                    // convert CNY to USD
                }
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                invalidInput = true;
                System.err.print("Please enter a valid CURRENCY: ");  // prompts user for currency ONLY
            }
        } while (invalidInput);

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        invalidInput = true;
        System.err.print("Please enter the VALUE followed by the CURRENCY: ");
        }
} while (invalidInput);
```

The outer do-while loop runs as long as `invalidInput` is `true`. At the beginning of the first `try` block, `invalidInput` is `false`, and it remains `false` unless the user enters an invalid input (e.g. blank input or non-numeric). Here, `invalidInput` becomes `true`, and the program loops back to the top of the `try` block after re-prompting the user for both `moneyInput` and `currency`.

Next, I wanted to find someway to check the validity of `moneyInput` and `currency` separately. The first set of nested Scanners is meant to process `moneyInput`. If the user inputs something invalid, it will re-prompt the user `Please enter the VALUE followed by the CURRENCY:`, and it will continue to do so until something valid is entered.

I then wanted to add the exact same functionality to check `currency` exclusively. This is the intended purpose of the second set of nested scanners (`lineScan2`). If a valid input is entered for `moneyInput` but not for `currency`, e.g. `100.00 abc`, I'd like the program to retain the value of `moneyInput`, re-prompt the user for only `currency`, and continue to do so until a valid currency is entered (including if the user enters a blank input).

Here are some problems I'm running into:

[image]

The program is only reading `moneyInput` in the first line, instead of reading both `moneyInput` and `currency`. Secondly, for each input, the user must press [return] twice (note each of the empty lines in between each input).

The program also terminates inconsistently. In the image example above, after it finally accepts a valid `moneyInput` and `currency` and converts the value, the program does not terminate. It terminates prematurely if the `moneyInput` is entered first, followed by an invalid `currency` on a second line, like so:

[image]

But here, it terminates properly after a successful run (although this still isn't exactly right because it only is "successful" if `moneyInput` and `currency` are input on separate lines; ideally, the user should be able to enter both on the same line and the program prints the appropriate conversion):

[image]

However, one thing the program does do well is responding repeatedly to invalid (specifically, blank inputs):

[image]

And actually, in the case above, aside from the fact that [return] had to be entered twice when prompting for `moneyInput` and that it didn't terminate after a successful run, everything is working exactly as desired:

> the user gets to try repeatedly until a valid input, and in the case
>   where `moneyInput` is valid but `currency` is not, the user only has
>   to enter a valid input for `currency` (i.e. they don't have to
>   re-enter `moneyInput` when only the `currency` was invalid).

So overall I am looking for ways to modify the code above to achieve the desired results. As mentioned in the comment section of the linked question at the very top of this post, another method I tried was another do-while loop inside (in place of the inner do-while loop) to check currency, and this worked except for when a blank input was entered, which is basically problem I had at the beginning of [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471220/how-to-get-java-scanner-to-acknowledge-blank-input/38471264) (here is my code: [pastebin.com/raw/CT0qjBPk](http://pastebin.com/raw/CT0qjBPk) and example screenshots: [imgur.com/a/mjfaL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IjRp.jpg)).

Sorry if this post is excessively specific and lengthy. I am a beginner programmer and trying to study Java as thoroughly as possible, and this process of improving code has been of great educational value. Thanks so much for reading and providing feedback.

Comment: you needn't catch NPE

Comment: you're right, I left that there for some reason while testing and running the program. I'll remove it from my code and this post

Comment: also, you'd better use one scanner instance

Comment: Using multiple (nested) scanners (specifically `lineScan`) was a solution provided by user dimo414 in the linked post. The other scanner `lineScan2` was to more easily show that that was where I tried inputting a second group of nested scanners, but the outcome should be the same whether `lineScan` or `lineScan2` was used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is overly-complex because you're using `input` in several different places. Here's essentially the pattern I suggested in my answer to your previous question:

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    doSomethingWithALineOfInput(line);
  }
}
```

Here's roughly what your code is doing:

```
boolean invalidInput = false;
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    do {
      String line = input.nextLine();
      invalidInput |= doSomethingWithALineOfInput(line);
      do {
        String line2 = input.nextLine();
        invalidInput |= doSomethingWithASecondLineOfInput(line2);
      } while (invalidInput);
    } while (invalidInput);
  }
}
```

Notice in particular that you're calling `input.nextLine()` in two separate places, which makes your code hard to reason about. One of the primary goals when programming is to reduce your problem into smaller subproblems - interleaving `input.nextLine()` calls everywhere (let alone inside nested do-while loops) forces you to continue dealing with one big problem.

So instead of mixing your line-processing and your token-processing code together, isolate them from each other. The *only* thing that should interact with `input` is the very outer `while` loop. Once you've read a line you're done with `input` for the remainder of that iteration.

Consider something like this (notice the use of a class to contain the values as we read them in):

```
class PromptForMoney {
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private String currency;

  public void prompt(Scanner in) {
    System.out.print("Enter an amount of money and currency to convert: ");
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
      try {
        processLine(in.nextLine());
        return;
      } catch (InputMismatchException | NoSuchElementException e) {
        // we use the exception message to describe the problem to the user
        // if Scanner generates exceptions with unclear messages you can
        // catch them in processLine() and throw your own with a better message.
        System.out.print("Invalid input - " + e.getMessage() + ": ");
      }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException(
        "No more input to read, but a valid amount or currency was not entered.");
  }

  private void processLine(String line) {
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    if (amount == null) {
      // this line will raise an exception if the line is empty
      // or if it doesn't start with numerical token
      amount = lineScanner.nextBigDecimal();
    }
    if (currency == null) {
      // this line will raise an exception if the user didn't specify a currency
      String c = lineScanner.next();
      if (isValidCurrency(c)) {
        currency = c;
      } else {
        throw new InputMismatchException(c + " is not a valid currency");
      }
    }
    // if we get this far without raising an exception we've read a valid
    // amount and currency from the user.
  }
}
```

Notice how `prompt()` deals solely with lines, and `processLine()` deals solely with the contents of a single line. This cleanly separates the problem into smaller, easier-to-reason-about parts.

You'd use `PromptForMoney` like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  PromptForMoney prompt = new PromptForMoney();
  try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    prompt.prompt(in);
  }
  System.out.println(convert(prompt.getAmount(), prompt.getCurrency());
}
```

There's another separation of concerns - only `main()` is responsible for directly interacting with `System.in`. As far as `PromptForMoney` is concerned its `Scanner` could be backed by a string or a file and it would work exactly the same.

---

*Caveat*: there are some best practices I'm not emphasizing for the sake of space and simplicity (e.g. preferring `final` instance variables). If you're interested in improving your code quality even further I strongly suggest reading [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) which goes into great detail about Java design patterns.

Comment: If I replace the final line in `main` with my method for converting CNY and USD, everything works great (see: http://pastebin.com/jJ6YdSAt). Now, how would I define that portion separately as another function named `convert`, so that whole chunk could just be replaced with `System.out.println(convert(prompt.amount));`? I tried to follow the examples of `prompt` and `processLine`, but I didn't know what format the argument list should be in. For example, I tried unsuccessfully to define `private void convert(BigDecimal prompt.amount)`

Comment: I tried defining `private static void convert( BigDecimal amount, String currency )`, like so http://pastebin.com/Vt8Sx9rV , but I got this result (http://imgur.com/a/95q06) in the IDE. So basically I am having trouble defining this portion as a new function.

Comment: Your `convert()` method is `void` - it should return something (presumably a `BigDecimal`) if you want to be able to print its result. Instead of having `println()` statements inside `convert()` the method should return the converted amount then you can print *that*. If that isn't clear enough I'd suggest posting a new question (feel free to link me to it and I'll try to answer). Comments don't work well for follow up questions.

Comment: oh my god i figured it out! thank you so much for being so patient and responsive, you've really helped me improve so much just from this 1 basic project :)

Comment: Hi, I just have one last question. This is inspired by your caveat of "best practices" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557212/returning-null-in-a-method-that-accounts-for-multiple-conditions)